# Get value from IO rather than the computation itself

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, interpreter, io-monad

Being quite new to Haskell, I'm currently trying to improve my skills by writing an interpreter for a simple imperative toy language.

One of the expressions in this language is `input`, which reads a single integer from standard input. However, when I assign the value of this expression to a variable and then use this variable later, it seems ot me that I actually stored the *computation* of reading a value rather the read value itself. This means that e.g. the statements

```
x = input;
y = x + x;
```

will cause the interpreter to invoke the input procedure *three* times rather than one.

Internally in the evaluator module, I use a `Map` to store the values of variables. Because I need to deal with IO, this gets wrapped in an `IO` monad, as immortalized in the following minimal example:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type State = Map.Map String Int
type Op = Int -> Int -> Int

input :: String -> IO State -> IO State
input x state = do line <- getLine
                   st <- state
                   return $ Map.insert x (read line) st

get :: String -> IO State -> IO Int
get x state = do st <- state
                 return $ case Map.lookup x st of
                            Just i -> i

eval :: String -> Op -> String -> IO State -> IO Int
eval l op r state = do i <- get l state
                       j <- get r state
                       return $ op i j

main :: IO ()
main = do let state = return Map.empty
          let state' = input "x" state
          val <- eval "x" (+) "x" state'
          putStrLn . show $ val
```

The second line in the `main` function simulates the assignment of `x`, while the third line simulates the evaluation of the binary `+` operator.

My question is: How do I get around this, such that the code above only inputs once? I suspect that it is the `IO`-wrapping that causes the problem, but as we're dealing with IO I see no way out of that..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that `IO State` is not an actual state, but instead the specification for an `IO` machine which eventually produces a `State`. Let's consider `input` as an *`IO`-machine transformer*

```
input :: String -> IO State -> IO State
input x state = do line <- getLine
                   st <- state
                   return $ Map.insert x (read line) st
```

Here, provided a machine for producing a state, we create a bigger machine which takes that passed state and adding a `read` from an input line. Again, to be clear, `input name st` is an `IO`-machine which is a slight modification of the `IO`-machine `st`.

Let's now examine `get`

```
get :: String -> IO State -> IO Int
get x state = do st <- state
                 return $ case Map.lookup x st of
                            Just i -> i
```

Here we have another `IO`-machine transformer. Given a name and an `IO`-machine which produces a `State`, `get` will produce an `IO`-machine which returns a number. Note again that `get name st` is fixed to always use the state produced by the (fixed, input) `IO`-machine `st`.

Let's combine these pieces in `eval`

```
eval :: String -> Op -> String -> IO State -> IO Int
eval l op r state = do i <- get l state
                       j <- get r state
                       return $ op i j
```

Here we call `get l` and `get r` each on the same `IO`-machine `state` and thus produce two (completely independent) `IO`-machines `get l state` and `get r state`. We then evaluate their `IO` effects one after another and return the `op`-combination of their results.

Let's examine the kinds of `IO`-machines built in `main`. In the first line we produce a *trivial `IO`-machine*, called `state`, written `return Map.empty`. This `IO`-machine, each time it's run, performs no side effects in order to return a *fresh*, blank `Map.Map`.

In the second line, we produce a new kind of `IO`-machine called `state'`. This `IO`-machine is based off of the `state` `IO`-machine, but it also requests an input line. Thus, to be clear, each time `state'` runs, a fresh `Map.Map` is generated and then an input line is read to read some `Int`, stored at `"x"`.

It should be clear where this is going, but now when we examine the third line we see that we pass `state'`, the `IO`-machine, into `eval`. Previously we stated that `eval` runs its input `IO`-machine twice, once for each name, and then combines the results. By this point it should be clear what's happening.

All together, we build a certain kind of machine which draws input and reads it as an integer, assigning it to a name in a blank `Map.Map`. We then build this `IO`-machine into a larger one which uses the first `IO`-machine twice, in two separate invocations, in order to collect data and combine it with an `Op`.

Finally, we run this `eval` machine using `do` notation (the `(<-)` arrow indicates running the machine). Clearly it should collect two separate lines.

---

So what do we really want to do? Well, we need to simulate ambient state in the `IO` monad, not just pass around `Map.Map`s. This is easy to do by using an `IORef`.

```
import Data.IORef

input :: IORef State -> String -> IO ()
input ref name = do
  line <- getLine
  modifyIORef ref (Map.insert name (read line))

eval :: IORef State -> Op -> String -> String -> IO Int
eval ref op l r = do
  stateSnapshot <- readIORef ref
  let Just i = Map.lookup l stateSnapshot
      Just j = Map.lookup l stateSnapshot
  return (op i j)

main = do
  st <- newIORef Map.empty   -- create a blank state, embedded into IO, not a value
  input st "x"               -- request input *once*
  val <- eval st (+) "x" "x" -- compute the op
  putStrLn . show $ val
```

Comment: Your `modifyIORef` invocation is missing its `ref` argument, and refers to a nonexistent variable `x`. What did you mean to do here?

Comment: Ah, I meant to copy and paste better. Fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's fine to wrap your actions such as `getLine` in `IO`, but to me it looks like your problem is that you're trying to pass your state in the `IO` monad.  Instead, I think this is probably time you get introduced to monad transformers and how they'll let you layer the `IO` and `State` monads to get the functionality of both in one.

Monad transformers are a pretty complex topic and it'll take a while to get to where you're comfortable with them (I'm still learning new things all the time about them), but they're a very useful tool when you need to layer multiple monads.  You'll need the `mtl` library to follow this example.

First, imports

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Monad.State
```

Then types

```
type Op = Int -> Int -> Int
-- Renamed to not conflict with Control.Monad.State.State
type AppState = Map.Map String Int
type Interpreter a = StateT AppState IO a
```

Here `Interpreter` is the `Monad` in which we'll build our interpreter.  We also need a way to run the interpreter

```
-- A utility function for kicking off an interpreter
runInterpreter :: Interpreter a -> IO a
runInterpreter interp = evalStateT interp Map.empty
```

I figured defaulting to `Map.empty` was sufficient.

Now, we can build our interpreter actions in our new monad.  First we start with `input`.  Instead of returning our new state, we just modify what is current in our map:

```
input :: String -> Interpreter ()
input x = do
    -- IO actions have to be passed to liftIO
    line <- liftIO getLine
    -- modify is a member of the MonadState typeclass, which StateT implements
    modify (Map.insert x (read line))
```

I had to rename `get` so that it didn't conflict with `get` from `Control.Monad.State`, but it does basically the same thing as before, it just takes our map and looks up that variable in it.

```
-- Had to rename to not conflict with Control.Monad.State.get
-- Also returns Maybe Int because it's safer
getVar :: String -> Interpreter (Maybe Int)
getVar x = do
    -- get is a member of MonadState
    vars <- get
    return $ Map.lookup x vars
-- or
-- get x = fmap (Map.lookup x) get
```

Next, `eval` now just looks up each variable in our map, then uses `liftM2` to keep the return value as `Maybe Int`.  I prefer the safety of `Maybe`, but you can rewrite it if you prefer

```
eval :: String -> Op -> String -> Interpreter (Maybe Int)
eval l op r = do
    i <- getVar l
    j <- getVar r
    -- liftM2 op :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
    return $ liftM2 op i j
```

Finally, we write our sample program.  It stores user input to the variable `"x"`, adds it to itself, and prints out the result.

```
-- Now we can write our actions in our own monad
program :: Interpreter ()
program = do
    input "x"
    y <- eval "x" (+) "x"
    case y of
        Just y' -> liftIO $ putStrLn $ "y = " ++ show y'
        Nothing -> liftIO $ putStrLn "Error!"

-- main is kept very simple
main :: IO ()
main = runInterpreter program
```

The basic idea is that there is a "base" monad, here `IO`, and these actions are "lifted" up to the "parent" monad, here `StateT AppState`.  There is a typeclass implementation for the different state operations `get`, `put`, and `modify` in the `MonadState` typeclass, which `StateT` implements, and in order to lift `IO` actions there's a pre-made `liftIO` function that "lifts" `IO` actions to the parent monad.  Now we don't have to worry about passing around our state explicitly, we can still perform IO, and it has even simplified the code!

I would recommend reading the Real World Haskell chapter on monad transformers to get a better feel for them.  There are other useful ones as well, such as `ErrorT` for handling errors, `ReaderT` for static configuration, `WriterT` for aggregating results (usually used for logging), and many others.  These can be layered into what is called a *transformer stack*, and it's not too difficult to make your own either.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing an `IO State`, you can pass `State` and then use higher-level functions to deal with IO. You can go further and make `get` and `eval` free from side-effects:

```
input :: String -> State -> IO State
input x state = do
    line <- getLine
    return $ Map.insert x (read line) state

get :: String -> State -> Int
get x state = case Map.lookup x state of
                Just i -> i

eval :: String -> Op -> String -> State -> Int
eval l op r state = let i = get l state
                        j = get r state
                    in  op i j

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let state = Map.empty
    state' <- input "x" state
    let val = eval "x" (+) "x" state'
    putStrLn . show $ val
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually building an interpreter, you'll presumably have a list of instructions to execute at some point.

This is my rough translation of your code (although I'm only a beginner myself)

```
import Data.Map (Map, empty, insert, (!))
import Control.Monad (foldM)                                                        

type ValMap = Map String Int                                                        

instrRead :: String -> ValMap -> IO ValMap                                          
instrRead varname mem = do                                                          
    putStr "Enter an int: "                                                         
    line <- getLine                                                                 
    let intval = (read line)::Int                                                   
    return $ insert varname intval mem                                              

instrAdd :: String -> String -> String -> ValMap -> IO ValMap                       
instrAdd varname l r mem = do                                                       
    return $ insert varname result mem                                              
    where result = (mem ! l) + (mem ! r)                                            

apply :: ValMap -> (ValMap -> IO ValMap) -> IO ValMap                               
apply mem instr = instr mem                                                         

main = do                                                                           
    let mem0 = empty                                                                
    let instructions = [ instrRead "x", instrAdd "y" "x" "x" ]                      
    final <- foldM apply mem0 instructions                                          
    print (final ! "y")                                                             
    putStrLn "done"
```

The `foldM` applies a function (`apply`) to a start value (`mem0`) and a list (`instructions`) but does so within a monad.